# Why does "unexcelled" mean very excellent when it should mean not excellent?

Tags: meaning

I was reading a real estate ad and it said, "Unexcelled" and it means amazing, top of the line, nothing can be better, obviously?

But here's the thing, I've always learned that un- meant the opposite or the negative. So why is "unexcelled" going against that common rule? Where does that "unexcelled" come to the point that it means the best rather than "not excellent."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **[Excel](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/excel) is a *verb*.**

  > 1. to surpass others or be superior in some respect or area; do extremely well
  > 2. to surpass; be superior to; outdo

  If something *excels*, it surpasses other things in some manner.  *Excelled* is the past tense of *excel*.  To say "Jimmy excelled at his piano recital" means that his performance was good relative to his peers.
- **[Unexcelled](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unexcelled) is an *adjective***.

  > 1. incapable of being bettered or improved upon : unsurpassed, superb

  "Unexcelled” is used to describe something which is not excelled (by other things). Thus, this does not go against the "common rule" you stated in your question; rather, something is "unexcelled" precisely because it is not excelled (or surpassed) by other things.